# Expected value and dimensional analysis

Tags: statistics, definition, expected-value

[The](https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/probability-and-statistics/expected-value/) [standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Absolutely_continuous_case) [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExpectationValue.html) [of](https://www.rapidtables.com/math/probability/Expectation.html) [expected](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Ekr2248/4109/chapter4.pdf) [value](https://store.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/fmi/statist/education/Virtual_Labs/expect/expect2.html) $E(x)$ of a continuous distribution $\rho(x)$ is given by
$$
E(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} x \rho(x) dx
$$

> Expected value is exactly what you might think it means intuitively: the return you can expect for some kind of action, like how many questions you might get right if you guess on a multiple choice test.

This is fine whenever $x$ has no units, such as tossing an infinite dimensional coin. Otherwise, however, **this definition has incorrect units**. For instance,

> Suppose $\rho(x)$ is a distribution describing the probability of a ball landing at point $x$, so that $E(x)$ is the mean value of position landing. We expec it to have units of position, obviously. However, $\int x \rho(x) dx$ has units of position^2.

Where is the mistake? It could be in the definition of $E(x)$. Replacing it with
$$
E(x) = \dfrac{\int x \rho(x) dx}{\int \rho(x) dx}
$$
Now, dimensional analysis matches our expectations, and since $\int \rho(x) dx = 1$ (with units!) anyway, the original expression is not lost. Two piece of evidence in favor of this definition are presented below.

> **Quantum mechanics:**
>
> In QM, $\psi^2(x)$ is a function describing the probability of finding
> a particle at point $x$, and is expected value is *defined* as
> $$ E(x) = \dfrac{\int x \psi^2(x) dx}{\int \psi^2(x) dx} $$
> Even though  $\psi$ is in $L^2$, $\int \psi^2(x) dx$ need not be $1$.
> If it is, though, the original expression for $E(x)$ is recovered
> (with correct units).
>
> **Weighted arithmetic mean:**
>
> The definition of $E(x)$ many times comes from a generalization
> weigthed arithmetic mean to the continuous case.
> $$ \bar{x} = \frac{\sum w_i x_i}{\sum w_i} $$
> From this point of view, the proposed expression is more similar to
> the above than the standard. It just happens that if the weigths
> describe probabilities, then $\sum w_i = 1$, again.

I ask **is the proposed definition of $E(x)$ correct**? Otherwise, **how does the original definition of $E(x)$ yields correct units?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake lies in the fact that you think $\rho(x)$ is unit-less. It is in fact a probability *density*, and a careful inspection of its definition tells you that it has units of $[\mbox{Probability}] / [x] = [x]^{-1}$ This is because, by definition, $\rho(x)\Delta x$, for small $\Delta x$ gives you the approximate probability of falling into a bin $[x,x+\Delta x]$. Probability on its own is unit less (think of it as a weight), but I've included to emphasize density.

Comment: Since $\psi^2$ is a probability density, it should have units of $[x]^{-1}$. So what are the units of $\psi$?

Comment: @big-lion: In quantum mechanics, $\psi$ is defined such that $|\psi|^2$ corresponds to probability density. So the units of $\psi$ are $1/\sqrt{x}$ (or possible $1/\sqrt{p}$ if you're in momentum space)